# It is possible to use std::rc::Rc with a trait type?

Tags: rust

The code looks like this:

```
// Simplified
pub trait Field: Send + Sync + Clone {
    fn name(&self);
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub enum Select {
    SelectOnly(Vec<Rc<Field>>),
    SelectAll
}
```

The error is:

```
the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Field+'static`
```

Is there any other way to have the vector with reference-counted **immutable** objects of trait type?

I suppose that I can rewrite the code like this:

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
pub enum Select {
    SelectOnly(Vec<Rc<Box<Field>>>),
    SelectAll
}
```

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it should be possible with DST, but Rust is not there just yet. The major motivation for DST was exactly the desire to use trait objects with any kind of smart pointer. As far as I know, this should be possible by 1.0 release.

As a temporary workaround, indeed, you can use `Rc<Box<T>>`, though this kind of double indirection is unfortunate.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create an trait object with an `Rc` as of Rust 1.1. This compiles:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Field: Send + Sync {
    fn name(&self);
}

enum Select {
    Only(Vec<Rc<Field>>),
    All,
}

// ---

struct Example;
impl Field for Example {
    fn name(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let fields: Vec<Rc<Field>> = vec![Rc::new(Example)];
    Select::Only(fields);
}
```

Note that your original example used `Clone`, but you cannot make such a trait into a trait object because it is [not object safe](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md). I've removed it to answer the question.

I also removed the redundancy of the enum variant names.

Comment: If you replace `Rc` with `RefCell`, it does not compile. But `RefCell<T>` takes `T: ?Sized` (in its definition, just like `Rc`) now. What am I missing?

Comment: Thought I would answer it myself -- `RefCell<Field>` is a valid type, but is also unsized. `RefCell` does not implement `CoerceUnsized` (see [RFC-0982](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0982-dst-coercion.md))

Comment: rustc 1.20.0-nightly (622e7e648 2017-06-21)
error[E0038]: the trait `Field` cannot be made into an object
 --> <anon>:9:16
  |
9 |     SelectOnly(Rc<Field>),
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Field` cannot be made into an object
  |
  = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`

error: aborting due to previous error(s)

Comment: @Yash huh wonder how it ever worked originally. Thankfully that is an orthogonal problem to the question asked in the title, so I've removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

It will be possible after [#18248](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18248) and [#16918](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16918).